# PHP registered shutdown function not called sometimes

Tags: php

I want to do a longtime job and i can't modify max execution time, so i take a solution: **when the script is going to shutdown, the script will send a http request to itself, so the script can continue to run.**
This is my test script t.php

```
<?php 
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));

function post_request_async($url, ARRAY $data) {
    // Convert the data array into URL Parameters like a=b&foo=bar etc.
    $data = http_build_query($data);
    // parse the given URL
    $url = parse_url($url);
    $host = $url['host'];
    $path = $url['path'];
    $port = isset($url['port']) ? $url['port'] : "80";
    $fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 5);
    if ($fp){
        $req = "";
        $req.="POST $path HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $req.="Host: $host\r\n";
        $req.="Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $req.="Content-length: ". strlen($data) ."\r\n";
        $req.="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        $req.= $data;
        fputs($fp, $req);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}

set_time_limit(10);
register_shutdown_function("shutdown_func");

file_put_contents(ROOT.DS."zz.txt", date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." start -->".PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

function shutdown_func(){
    file_put_contents(ROOT.DS."zz.txt", date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." shutdown_func -->".PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    post_request_async("http://127.0.0.1/t.php", array());
    exit();
}

for(;;) {
    sleep(2);
}
?>
```

But the result is strange:
zz.txt

```
2012-05-16 10:11:42 start -->
2012-05-16 10:11:54 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:11:54 start -->
2012-05-16 10:12:04 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:12:04 start -->
2012-05-16 10:12:14 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:12:14 start -->
2012-05-16 10:12:26 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:12:26 start -->
2012-05-16 10:12:38 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:12:38 start -->
2012-05-16 10:12:48 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:12:48 start -->
2012-05-16 10:12:58 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:12:58 start -->
2012-05-16 10:13:08 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:13:08 start -->
2012-05-16 10:13:18 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:13:18 start -->
2012-05-16 10:13:28 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:13:28 start -->
2012-05-16 10:13:40 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:13:40 start -->
2012-05-16 10:13:50 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:13:50 start -->
2012-05-16 10:14:02 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:14:02 start -->
2012-05-16 10:14:14 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:14:14 start -->
2012-05-16 10:14:26 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:14:26 start -->
2012-05-16 10:14:36 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:14:36 start -->
2012-05-16 10:14:48 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:14:48 start -->
2012-05-16 10:14:58 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:14:58 start -->
2012-05-16 10:15:08 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:15:08 start -->
2012-05-16 10:15:18 shutdown_func -->
2012-05-16 10:15:18 start -->
```

php_errors.log

```
[16-May-2012 02:11:54 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:12:04 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:12:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:12:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:12:38 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:12:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:12:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:13:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:13:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:13:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:13:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:13:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:14:02 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:14:14 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:14:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:14:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:14:48 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:14:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:15:08 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:15:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:15:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 41
[16-May-2012 02:15:28 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 33
```

Looks like the shutdown function get called for about 22 times and suddenly didn't get called.

My php version is 5.3.9 and server is IIS 7.5
Really need some help!
Thanks very much!

**-----------------------Update 1--------------------------------------------**

After some digging, I found a test script in php source. It looks like registered shutdown function could timeout.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(1);
register_shutdown_function("plop");

function plop() {
    $ts = time();
    while(true) {
        if ((time()-$ts) > 2) {
            echo "Failed!";
            break;
        }
    }
}
plop();
?>
```

The result is:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 1 second exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 9

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 1 second exceeded in E:\eclipse_php_workspace\caijiche_new2\t.php on line 9
```

Comment: notice it dies on line 33 vs 41?

Comment: We can see, 2 time out errors were thrown at the same time[16-May-2012 02:15:28 UTC]. Isn't that strange ?

Comment: thats totally bizarre. maybe try logging process id's and other diagnostic info, you might glean something interesting from it.

Comment: @chris , I tried it again on apache, still reproducable. And I confirmed the script throw 2 time our errors which is weird. Below is the apache access.log :    `127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2012:12:09:57 +0800] "POST /t.php HTTP/1.0" 200 153
127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2012:12:10:07 +0800] "POST /t.php HTTP/1.0" 200 153
127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2012:12:10:17 +0800] "POST /t.php HTTP/1.0" 200 306`                                                                              **Notice the number 153 and 306, which means the last return 2 timeout error.**

Answer (score 0):

It takes 12 seconds from start to end (see your timers in zz.txt), max execution time is set to 10 seconds. So there's a problem.

Usually I set the time limit cut-off at (max-execution-time - 5 seconds), but as you only have 10 seconds, and a 2 second overlay, you should set your shutdown to 7 seconds.

---

If you launch this from a browser, it may be preferential to actual do the "call itself" from a META Refresh instruction. This way you can issue a small HTML page with status and meta refresh back to itself. (Also my preferred route for this!) Ignore if you're running a cron or other back-end process not from a browser.

---

Edit (to save typing too many comments) in response to "it's now stopped, but then comes back after a few minutes".

What I'm guessing is, if you still have the PHP script calling itself, it's probably burning more and more memory and never allowing iteslf to garbage collect. Each PHP script in Apache takes about 10MB Apache overhead, plus another 2-3MB of PHP script - so the more you call itself the more this will add up and eventually slow down.

So you need to go back to one of the suggestions:

a) If calling from a browser, as oposed to PHP calling itself, issue a

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://127.0.0.1/t.php">
   </head>
   <body>
     Echo going to <a href="http://127.0.0.1/t.php">http://127.0.0.1/t.php</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

This means that there is calling itself in the PHP script; PHP also gets to breathe and can garbage collect, although the break is not necessary with just one simple script runing - stopping the looping should sort it out.

Problems: if your connection should fail, or the internet should fail then the response won't happen and the script will break, so:

b) A variation of this is to create a bit of javascript that calls the server once every 10 seconds. Don't do anything after time-out as Javascript will just start the process again.

c) The best approach though, if you want this to run "forever", run the PHP script as a command line (php -q /var/www/html/Myphp.php > /dev/nul) from a cron job. Set the cron job to run every minute. Add a counter to the script that increments each time it calls itself and then stops after the 6th call (i.e. 1 minute). This way you're looping a max of 5 times before the script dies and allows itself to be cleaned up.

d) Alternatively, if you can write a quick shell script, just create shell script that calls the PHP comand line then waits 10 seconds and calls it again, 6 times. Trigger that script from a cron running each minute. This way you don't have the Apache overhead (saves sockets, saves memory) as well as avoiding the lopping issue.

e) There are other variations - depending on what permissions you've got on the server...

Not promising they will fix your problems, but a function calling itself endlessly is programming no-no, so I'd give at least the first one a stab to see if it works, then research the more complex ones.

Comment: But i still have question about register_shutdown_function. According to document, registered shutdown function still get called when script execution timeout. So it looks like the document is not right.

Comment: It _IS_ still getting called after script execition timeout. You can tell this for two reasons: a) zz.txt is getting updated, b) the script is looping. Both of these come from that function!

Comment: But how do you explain the last 2 lines in php_errors.log ?  We can see, 2 time out errors were thrown at the same time[16-May-2012 02:15:28 UTC]. Isn't that strange ?

Comment: And i modified as what you said, but still the same after few minutes.

Comment: Last two lines - never noticed, but probably the same as why it happens after a few minutes. I'll add something to the answer above.